# Free jqgrid with jquery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm having following error. Can someone help.
I'm migrating my application (that worked so far) using authentication feature on my VS 2017

I'm using jqGrid 3.5 downloaded from GitHub. Actually I can see the grid with the data in it but would generate the error in the console pan as soon as the page is shown.

[image]

Here are my codes:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //*** Définition de la grille principale et des sous-grilles ***
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: 'GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: [
            "Code",
            "Nom",
            "Prenoms",
            "Courriel",
            "Adresse Demandeur",
            "Ville",
            "Province",
            "Code Postal",
            "Téléphone",
            "Téléphone 2",
            "Fax",
            "Courriel 2",
            "Courriel 3",
            "Situation Matrimoniale",
            "Sexe",
            "Date de Naissance",
            "Revenu",
            "Occupation",
            "Scolarité",
            "Statut Legal",
            "Communauté",
            "Source d" + "information",
            "Handicapé",
            "Reference",
            "Remarques",
            "Photo",
            "Catégorie",
            "Nom du conseiller",
            "Prenoms su conseiller",
            "Date de Cloture du Dossier",
            "Date d'Ouverture du Dossier"
        ],
        colModel: [
            {
                key: true, name: 'Code_Demandeur', index: 'Code_Demandeur', width: 60, search: true, sorttype: 'string', searchoptions: {
                    sopt:
                        ['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn']
                }
            },
            {
                key: false, name: 'Nom_Demandeur', index: 'Nom_Demandeur', width: 120, search: true, sorttype: 'string', searchoptions: {
                    sopt:
                        ['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn']
                }
            },
            {
                key: false, name: 'Prenoms_Demandeur', index: 'Prenoms_Demandeur', width: 120, search: true, sorttype: 'string', searchoptions: {
                    sopt:
                        ['cn', 'eq', 'ne', 'bw', 'bn', 'ew', 'en', 'cn']
                }
            },
            {
                key: false, name: 'Courriel1_Demandeur', index: 'Courriel1_Demandeur', width: 100, search: false,
            },
            { key: false, name: 'Adresse_Demandeur', index: 'Adresse_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Ville', index: 'Ville', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Province', index: 'Province', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'CodePostal_Demandeur', index: 'CodePostal_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Tel1_Demandeur', index: 'Tel1_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Tel2_Demandeur', index: 'Tel2_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Tel3_Demandeur', index: 'Tel3_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Courriel2_Demandeur', index: 'Courriel2_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Courriel3_Demandeur', index: 'Courriel3_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'SitMat', index: 'SitMat', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Sexe', index: 'Sexe', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Date_Naissance_Demandeur', index: 'Date_Naissance_Demandeur', align: 'right', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Nom_TrancheRevenu', index: 'Nom_TrancheRevenu', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Occupation', index: 'Occupation', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Scolarite', index: 'Scolarite', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'StatutLegal', index: 'StatutLegal', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Communaute', index: 'Communaute', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'SourceInformation', index: 'SourceInformation', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Handicape', index: 'Handicape', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Reference', index: 'Reference', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Remarques_Demandeur', index: 'Remarques_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Photo', index: 'Photo', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Nom_Type_Demandeur', index: 'Nom_Type_Demandeur', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Nom_Conseiller', index: 'Nom_Conseiller', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Prenoms_Conseiller', index: 'Prenoms_Conseiller', hidden: true, },
            { key: false, name: 'Date_Cloture_Dossier', index: 'Date_Cloture_Dossier', align: 'right', hidden: true, },
            {
                key: false, name: 'Date_Ouverture_Dossier', index: 'Date_Ouverture_Dossier', align: 'right',
                formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'u', newformat: "d/m/Y" }, width: 70, search: false, hidden: true,
            },
        ],
        clearSearch: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        pager: $('#pager'),
        rowNum: 100000,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100000],
        //height: '100%',
        height: 400,
        emptyrecords: "Pas d'enregistrement à afficher",
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "0"
        },
        rownumbers: true,
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: false,
        sortname: 'Code_Demandeur',
        sortorder: "asc",
        loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            //*** Permet de remplacer l'option d'affichage du maximum d'enrégistrement (100000) par "Tout" ***
            $("option[value=100000]").text('Tout');
            //*** Permet de sélectionner une ligne d'enrégistrement spécifique après le chargement de la grille *** 
            if ($('#btnModifierProfile').val() != "")
                jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setSelection', $('#btnModifierProfile').val());
        },
        onSelectRow: function (ids) {
            var data = $("#grid").getRowData(ids);
            //*** Stocke le demandeur sélectionné dans la propriété d'un contrôle ***
            $('body').data('ddeurSelected', data);
            if (ids != null) {
                //*** Retrait des langues et des sources de revenu du demandeur ***
                $.getJSON(" ../Conseiller/GetLanguesDemandeur_MenuConseiller", { sIdDdeur: ids }, function (data1, status) {
                    var cpt = data1.rows.length;
                    var langMat = '';
                    var langAutre = [];
                    var srceRev = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < cpt; i++) {
                        var boolLangMat = data1.rows[i].LangueMaternelle;
                        var nomLang = data1.rows[i].Nom_Langue;
                        if (boolLangMat == true) {
                            langMat = nomLang;
                        } else {
                            langAutre.push(nomLang);
                        }
                    }
                    cpt = data1.sourceRevenu.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < cpt; i++) {
                        srceRev.push(data1.sourceRevenu[i].Nom_SourceRevenu);
                    };
                    document.getElementById('txtSourceRevenu').value = srceRev;
                    document.getElementById('langMater').value = langMat;
                    document.getElementById('langAutre').value = langAutre;
                    //*** Fin de retait des langues du demandeur ***
                    var add = data.Adresse_Demandeur;
                    var city = data.Ville;
                    var prov = data.Province;
                    //*** Formatage du code postal et des numéros de téléphone et fax ***
                    var cdePst = data.CodePostal_Demandeur;
                    var tel1 = data.Tel1_Demandeur.trim();
                    var tel2 = data.Tel2_Demandeur.trim();
                    var Fax = data.Tel3_Demandeur.trim();
                    if (cdePst != '') {
                        cdePst = cdePst.splice(3, 0, ' ');
                    };
                    if (tel1 != '') {
                        tel1 = tel1.splice(0, 0, '(');
                        tel1 = tel1.splice(4, 0, ') ');
                        tel1 = tel1.splice(10, 0, '-');
                    };
                    if (tel2 != '') {
                        tel2 = tel2.splice(0, 0, '(');
                        tel2 = tel2.splice(4, 0, ') ');
                        tel2 = tel2.splice(10, 0, '-');
                    };
                    if (Fax != '') {
                        Fax = Fax.splice(0, 0, '(');
                        Fax = Fax.splice(4, 0, ') ');
                        Fax = Fax.splice(10, 0, '-');
                    };
                    //*** Fin formatage des numéro de téléphone et fax ***

                    var cour2 = data.Courriel2_Demandeur;
                    var cour3 = data.Courriel3_Demandeur;
                    var sitMat = data.SitMat;
                    var Sexe = data.Sexe;
                    //*** Conversion et comparaison de la date ***
                    function formatJsonDate(jsonDate) {
                        var nais = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
                        var nais1 = new Date('1900-01-01');
                        if (nais.getTime() < nais1.getTime())
                            return '';
                        return nais.toLocaleDateString();
                    };
                    //*** Fin conversion de la date ***
                    var dteNais = formatJsonDate(data.Date_Naissance_Demandeur);
                    var dteOuvDossier = data.Date_Ouverture_Dossier;
                    var dteClotDossier = formatJsonDate(data.Date_Cloture_Dossier);
                    var conseiller = data.Prenoms_Conseiller + ' ' + data.Nom_Conseiller;
                    var revenu = data.Nom_TrancheRevenu;
                    var occupation = data.Occupation;
                    var scolarite = data.Scolarite;
                    var statLeg = data.StatutLegal;
                    var communaute = data.Communaute;
                    var sceInfor = data.SourceInformation;
                    var handicape = data.Handicape;
                    var ref = data.Reference;
                    var rem = data.Remarques_Demandeur;
                    var pic = data.Photo;
                    //var cat = data.Nom_Type_Demandeur;
                    document.getElementById('adresse').value = add + " - " + city + ", " + cdePst + " " + prov;
                    document.getElementById('tel1').value = tel1;
                    document.getElementById('tel2').value = tel2;
                    document.getElementById('fax').value = Fax;
                    document.getElementById('dteNais').value = dteNais;
                    document.getElementById('sitMat').value = sitMat;
                    document.getElementById('sex').value = Sexe;
                    if (handicape == 'true') {
                        document.getElementById('handi').checked = true;
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('handi').checked = false;
                    }
                    document.getElementById('statLeg').value = statLeg;
                    document.getElementById('comm').value = communaute;
                    if (pic) {
                        document.getElementById('picPath').innerHTML = '<img src="' + pic + '" class="img-rounded" style="width: 155px; height: 175px">';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('picPath').innerHTML = '<img src="../Images/profile-picture.png" class="img-rounded" style="max-width: 155px; max-height: 175px">';
                    }
                    document.getElementById('rev').value = revenu;
                    document.getElementById('occ').value = occupation;
                    document.getElementById('sco').value = scolarite;
                    document.getElementById('sceInfo').value = sceInfor;
                    document.getElementById('ref').value = ref;
                    document.getElementById('rem').value = rem;
                    document.getElementById('cour2').value = cour2;
                    document.getElementById('cour3').value = cour3;
                    document.getElementById('cons').value = conseiller;
                    document.getElementById('dteClosDos').value = dteClotDossier;
                    //document.getElementById('catDdeur').value = cat;

                    //*** Attribution du code demandeur comme Valeur du bouton "Modifier" ***
                    document.getElementById('btnModifierProfile').setAttribute("value", data.Code_Demandeur);
                    //*** Reinitialisation des autres onglets ainsi que les champs ***
                    ReinitialiserChamps();
                    $("#detailsPretsDdeur")
                        .setGridParam({ url: "GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller_PretsSubgrid?id=" + data.Code_Demandeur, page: 1 })
                        .setCaption("<b>Détail des prêts pour : " + data.Prenoms_Demandeur + ' ' + data.Nom_Demandeur + "</b>")
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    $("#detailsRemboursementsDdeur")
                        .setGridParam({ url: "GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller_RemboursementsSubgrid?id=" + data.Code_Demandeur, page: 1 })
                        .setCaption("<b>Détail des remboursements pour : " + data.Prenoms_Demandeur + ' ' + data.Nom_Demandeur + "</b>")
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    $("#detailsEntreprisesDdeur")
                        .setGridParam({ url: "GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller_EntreprisesSubgrid?id=" + data.Code_Demandeur, page: 1 })
                        .setCaption("<b>Détail des entreprises pour : " + data.Prenoms_Demandeur + ' ' + data.Nom_Demandeur + "</b>")
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    $("#detailsRencontresDdeur")
                        .setGridParam({ url: "GetDemandeurs_MenuConseiller_RencontresSubgrid?id=" + data.Code_Demandeur, page: 1 })
                        .setCaption("<b>Détail des rencontres pour : " + data.Prenoms_Demandeur + ' ' + data.Nom_Demandeur + "</b>")
                        .trigger('reloadGrid');
                });
            }
        }
    })

    jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: true, searchOnEnter: false, autosearch: true });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Catégorie Demandeurs (Liste des)";
    }
    <title></title>

    <link href="../content/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="../content/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    @*<script src="../content/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!--webfonts-->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700|Six+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!--//webfonts-->
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="../content/js/bootstrap.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                @* *** Fermer la fenêtre courante *** *@
                @Html.ActionLink("Fermer", null, null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", id = "close" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left; width:100%">
                @* *** Contrôle text caché permet d'envoyer la table choisie *@
                <input type="hidden" id="nomTableHidden" data-value="@ViewBag.Title" />
                <h2>Ajouter/Modifier/Suprimer une Catégorie de Demandeur</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- *** Lignes pour le table JQGrid *** -->
        <div style="padding-top: 10px" , class="row">
            <table id="grilleJqGrid_Demandeur_Categorie" style="width: 100%"></table>
            <div id="pager_Demandeur_Categorie"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @* *** Boutons d'action cachés pour Ajouter/Modifier/Supprimer un enregistrement *** *@
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAjouterDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Ajouter_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', null, 'Ajouter')">
        Ajouter une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalAjouter_Demandeur_Categorie").
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnModifierDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Modifier_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', this.id, 'Modifier')">
        Modifier une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalModifier_Demandeur_Categorie")
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSupprimerDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Supprimer_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', null, 'Supprimer')">
        Supprimer une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalSupprimer_Demandeur_Categorie")

  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of free jqGrid you use? Where is the code, which shows in which order you include JavaScript files in the HTML file? How one could help you if you post only screenshorts with some errors in your `MenuConseiller.js` file?

Comment: Here are the codes:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Catégorie Demandeurs (Liste des)";
    }
    <title></title>

    <link href="../content/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="../content/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    @*<script src="../content/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

Comment: <!--webfonts-->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700|Six+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!--//webfonts-->
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="../content/js/bootstrap.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: <body>
...
  <!-- *** Début table JQGrid *** -->
    <link href="../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @*** *En commentaire: conflit avec fenêtre modale ***@
    @*<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>*@
    @*** Fin commentaire ***@
    <script src="../Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/JqGrid_Scripts/MenuConseiller.js"></script>
    <!-- *** Fin table JQGrid *** -->

Comment: <!-- *** Script pour le modal *** -->
    <script src="../Scripts/JqGrid_Scripts/ModalForms.js"></script>
    <!-- *** Fin script pour le modal *** -->
    <!-- Référence pour les grilles -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/JqGrid_Scripts/AdminForms.js"></script>

    @* *** Custom ref files *** *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/css_custom/Admin_CRUD.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/Admin_CRUD.js"></script>
    @* *** Fin custom ref files *** *@
</body>

Comment: Please, click on "edit" link below your question and append the text with additional information. Text editor allows format the code in readable form. If you post pictures, you should cut unneeded information too. You still not answered on my first question: **which version of jqGrid you use (can use)?** It's really important to know

Answer (score 0):

Actually the line referring to    @* *@
has nothing to do there.